# Prove that the following map is not open

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a map from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}^2$ defined in the follwoing way:
$f(z_1,z_2)=(z_1z_2,z_1)$. I cannot see why this is not open, any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no open set containing $(0,0)$, contained in the image of $f$.

Comment: I got it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a hint...

Suppose we discuss open sets $U \times V \subset \Bbb{C}^2$.

For $z_2 = 0$, $\{z_1 z_2 : z_1 \in U \}$ is a point, not an open set, whereas for all $z_2 \neq 0$, $\{z_1 z_2 : z_1 \in U \}$ is a (scaled, rotated, hence open) copy of $U$.  This suggests we want $0 \in V$.